# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1172 Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I try to insert multiple rows in one query I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1172 Result
>   consisted of more than one row

Here's the code I used :

```
  public function submitAnswers($q)
   {
    try
      {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `result_answers` (`resultID`, `questionID`, `answerID`, `isTrue`,`textAnswer`) VALUES ';
        foreach($q as $question => $answer){
        if($answer[0] == 0){
        for($i = 1;$i < count($answer);$i++){
            $sql .= '((select max(id) from result r where r.studentID = :studentID), ' . $question . ', ' . $answer[$i] .', NULL, NULL),';}
        }elseif($answer[0] == 1){
          $sql .= '((select max(id) from result r where r.studentID = :studentID), ' . $question . ', NULL, ' . $answer[1] .', NULL),';
        }elseif($answer[0] == 2){
          $sql .= '((select max(id) from result r where r.studentID = :studentID), ' . $question . ', NULL, NULL, "' . $answer[1] .'"),';
        }
        }
          $query = rtrim($sql,',');
         $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($query);
         $stmt->bindparam(":studentID",$_SESSION['student']->id);

         $stmt->execute();

         return true;
      }
    catch(PDOException $e)
      {
         echo $e->getMessage();
         return false;
      }
   }
```

When I execute the `$query` output directly in my database, rows are successfully inserted, so I think for some reason PDO is not allowing multi-rows insertion.

Comment: It is a SQL error, not PDO. The values go in the `select` list. Something like `select max(id), $question . ', ' . $answer[$i] .', NULL, NULL from result r where r.studentID = :studentID`. Your `$question` and `$answer[$i]` should be bound as well.

Comment: i tried it on the database and it works but how can i implement it with multiple rows
i used union but i don't think it's a good option for performance @user3783243

Answer (score 0):

I have find out the cause of the issue. It turned out that there was a **TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT** on the table that I was inserting data, and inside the trigger was a SELECT INTO statement that was returning more than one row.